# In "Batman vs Superman: Dawn of Justice", why does Superman ignore Lex's gang?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Batman is chasing Lex's thugs, who are transporting the Kryptonite rock to Lex's labs. Lots of explosions, guns, etc.
All of a sudden, the Batmobile runs into Superman, who confronts Batman, telling him to "Hang up the suit".

At this moment why does Superman totally disregard Lex's gang, allowing them to escape with the Kryptonite.  Admittedly, Supes doesn't know that's what they have, and yes he wants to confront Batman - but isn't he at least curious?  Wouldn't it be due diligence for him to ask or find out why Batman was chasing them in the first place, and why they were so heavily armed?

I'm trying to suspend my disbelief, but I'm struggling to get past this point.

Comment: Because plot reasons

Comment: The entire plot revolves around Supes' and the Bat's mutual obsession of each other. Clearly, they are both being blinded by this to other concerns--in Superman's case, to truth, justice and the American way. He probably figured Batman was going to murder the thugs if he caught them, so stopping Batman was more important than catching some petty criminals.

Comment: @RobJarvis that's kind of my point - these were obviously more than just 'petty' criminals, armed as they were with RPGs and vehicle-mounted chain guns!